# Android: SocketIO is not establishing connection with 'https'

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have successfully established connection with a server ip address along with port number using `http` but am unable to establish connection using `https`.

This is how i am using socketio object with SSL:

```
try {
                   SocketIO.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }        

         final SocketIO socketio = new SocketIO("https://192.168.1.29:6536");
```

I have used the following js file by creating local server:

```
var https = require('https');
//var io  = require('socket.io');  
var fs = require('fs');
//var server = io.listen(6536);

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./NodeKey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./NodeCer.pem')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(6536);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

console.log('socket started'); 

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
    console.log('Hello from android'); 
        socket.emit('response', {msg: 'welcome'});
        socket.on('user', function(data) {

});
```

I am getting handshake error

I am using socketio version 0.9.16

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/62

Comment: I am using SocketIO library with version 0.9.16.

Comment: Question is not clear since there no log message. Probably, you may need to get intermediate certificates add to your chain. Previously, I encountered this issue and fixed by adding intermediate certs.